# Pseudo dropdown select working only once

Tags: javascript, jquery

Trying to create a pseudo dropdown select, What I am trying to do is when a `li` is clicked, the content of `<span></span>` is replaced with the content of the clicked `li`

The problem is that its working only for the first click, not for the subsequent ones. What am I missing here.

Here is the unordered list

```
            <div id="dd" class="language-selection" tabindex="1"><span>Language</span>
                <ul class="dropdown">
                    <li>Profile</li>
                    <li>Settings</li>
                    <li>Log out</li>
                </ul>
            </div>
```

Here is the jQuery code :

```
        jQuery('.language-selection ul li').click(function(){
            var languageSelection = jQuery(this).text();
            jQuery('.language-selection span').replaceWith(languageSelection);
        });
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`replaceWith` replaces the actual element with new contents passed as argument to this method,due to which it works for first time. afterwords no span element exist on first replacement.

Use `.text()` instead of `replaceWith` to set text to element.:

```
jQuery('.language-selection span').text(languageSelection);
```

Comment: It worked, Any reason why `replaceWith` works only once?

Comment: @SrikanthKoneru: added explanation in answer.

Comment: this is right and also he can use .replaceWith('<span>'+languageSelection+'</span>'); and it should work too

Comment: @Mohamed-Yousef: that wont. because newly added element will not have click event attached to it

Comment: My bad. click events are associated to li and not span.